# Is the Low Quality Posts algorithm also used for auto-flags in the 10k tools?

Tags: support, review, 10k-tools, low-quality-posts

Because I have 2k+ rep on a beta site, I have access to the moderator tools there. There just were some posts in the Low Quality Posts review queue that were probably auto-identified. But none of them appeared in the Tools. Also, yesterday an auto-VLQ flag appeared in the Tools, but the post that was flagged didn't appear in the Low Quality queue.

So, does the auto-flag feature use the same algorithm as the algorithm used in the Low Quality queue? If not, is there any other relationship between them?

Comment: It was... at some point.